# C# need to add random response with switch statement

Tags: c#, random, switch-statement, case

```
namespace _7._39
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
       {
        string response1;
        string response2;
        string response3;
        string response4;

        Random resp = new Random();

        bool correct = Question();// Create a value to call the question method

        if (correct== true)// when the answer is true it return very good
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Very Good!");
        }
        else// when the answer is false it returns to try again
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No please try again");
        }
    }
    public static bool Question()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();// we create a random number
        int num = rand.Next(1, 9);// first random number between 1 and 9
        int num1 = rand.Next(1, 9);// second random number between 1 and 9

        int ans = num * num1;// the value of multiplication between 1 and 2

        // asking what the two values are multiplied
        Console.WriteLine("What is"+ num.ToString()+ "*" +num1.ToString());
        // reads the users attempt 
        int attempt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (attempt == ans)// when the attempt is equal to the answer
        {
            return true;// its returns true bool
        }

        else// if it is false it says no please try again
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No please try again");
            return Question();// and creates a new question for the user
        }
    }
}
}
```

I need my correct== true and false to respond with a random response among 4 possible choices. I need to do this by doing a switch statement to issue each response. Also by using random to select which response comes up.

Very good!

Excellent!

Nice work!

Keep up the good work!

and 4 options for a false response as well

How can i implement this code into my current code?

```
response = resp.Next(1, 5);
                switch (response)
                {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Very Good!");
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Excellent!");
                    break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Nice Work!");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Keep up the good work!");
                    break;
                default;

            }
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question yet. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237 for more.

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: It is risky to use `new Random().Next()`. You should create a single `new Random()` instance, pass that to your handlers (like `Question`) and call `.Next()` on the shared instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var rnd = new Random();
Func<bool, string> getRespose = b =>
{
    var choices = b
        ? new [] { "Very good!", "Excellent!", "Nice work!", "Keep up the good work!", }
        : new [] { "Bad!", "V Bad!", "VV Bad!", "VVV Bad!", };

    return choices[rnd.Next(0, choices.Length)];
};
```

No need for a `switch` statement.

---

Or if you want it as a `switch`:

```
var rnd = new Random();
var choices = (string[])null;
switch (correct)
{
    case true:
        choices = new []
            { "Very good!", "Excellent!", "Nice work!", "Keep up the good work!", };
        break;
    case false:
        choices = new [] { "Bad!", "V Bad!", "VV Bad!", "VVV Bad!", };
        break;
}

var response = choices[rnd.Next(0, choices.Length)];
```

Or, with a `switch` and a `Func`:

```
var rnd = new Random();
Func<bool, string> getRespose = b =>
{
    var choices = (string[])null;
    switch (b)
    {
        case true:
            choices = new []
                { "Very good!", "Excellent!", "Nice work!", "Keep up the good work!", };
            break;
        case false:
            choices = new []
                { "Bad!", "V Bad!", "VV Bad!", "VVV Bad!", };
            break;
    }

    return choices[rnd.Next(0, choices.Length)];
};

var response = getRespose(correct);
```

Or as a "normal" function:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
private string GetRespose(bool b)
{
    var choices = (string[])null;
    switch (b)
    {
        case true:
            choices = new []
                { "Very good!", "Excellent!", "Nice work!", "Keep up the good work!", };
            break;
        case false:
            choices = new []
                { "Bad!", "V Bad!", "VV Bad!", "VVV Bad!", };
            break;
    }

    return choices[rnd.Next(0, choices.Length)];
}
```

Or as a "normal" function, but without the `switch`:

```
private Random rnd = new Random();
private string GetRespose(bool b)
{
    var choices = b
        ? new [] { "Very good!", "Excellent!", "Nice work!", "Keep up the good work!", }
        : new [] { "Bad!", "V Bad!", "VV Bad!", "VVV Bad!", };

    return choices[rnd.Next(0, choices.Length)];
}
```

Comment: I would like to use a switch because that is a method i know of, I see that your solution could work, however I do not understand the Func<> in C# yet.

Comment: @Bonetoad - I've added a bunch of variants for you. You'll see that you can do a `switch` combined with a `Func`. They are not mutually exclusive.